# Как такое написать?

Tags: javascript

В общем, есть класс Bot, а так же в нём имеется 2 метода: on, onText и они принимают 2 параметра. Мой вопрос такой, как добавить событие клика, а также добавление элемента в блок в on и text, но при этом, в этом событии у меня разная реализация.

То есть, у on у меня есть событие клика, после добавляет мое сообщение в блок и дальше своя реализация. Вот мне нужно такое же в text, но там своя реализация. Дублировать код, я считаю это тупо.

Вот мой код:

```
class Bot {
    on(type, listener) {
        if (events.indexOf(type) !== -1) {
            document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', e => {
                e.preventDefault()
                const message = document.querySelector('.form-control');
                listener({'text': message.value})
                // тут добавление message в блок
            })
        }
    }
    onText(regex, listener) {
        // тут нужно событие клика, а также добавление этого message в блок и своя реализация в это событие
    }
}
```

message это input text

Comment: Вынесете код в функцию и вызывайте там и там эту функцию, возможно передавая ей нужные параметры. А вообще, установка слушателей на каждый вызов метода не есть хорошо, если позже этот слушатель не удаляется

Comment: так это тупо в каждую функцию пихать реализацию клика и добавление сообщения в чат

Comment: Реализуйте клик в одном месте. Зачем вы запихиваете создание слушателя клика на каждый метод? Если вызовут 100 раз метод `on` у вас будет 100 слушателей `'submit'`

Comment: Так а как я реализую тогда метод onText? Мне в нём тоже нужно проверять, отправил ли сообщение и какое. А то, что вы говорите, типа сдалать отдельную функцию для клика, можете пожалуйста показать кодом?)

Comment: Не имея представления о том, как у вас что реализовано и чего вы хотите добиться, выразить это в коде очень сложно. Тем более что из вашего поста вообще не понятно, какого результата вы хотите добиться. Не дублировать код? - правильно! Как это сделать - дубли выносить в функции или отдельные методы и их вызывать.

Comment: Ну я вот не могу понять, как его правильно вынести и вызывать в других функциях. Просто добавить addEventListener, это понятно, но я же должен в нём реализацию добавить, которая будет у меня в on и onText